# onBluer is activated before the button's onClick to clear the input - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Before the button to clear the input is called the onBlur event is activated and my component is disassembled before clearing the text.

```
  export default function Search(): JSX.Element {
      const [search, setSearch] = useState('');
      const [isFocus, setIsFocus] = useState(false);
    
      const handleSearch = useCallback(e => {
        setSearch(e.target.value);
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <>
          <InputContainer>
            <IconSearch>
              <FiSearch color={isFocus ? backgroundOrange : '#A0ACB2'} />
            </IconSearch>
            <SearchInput
              placeholder="Qual cidade você procura?"
              onChange={handleSearch}
              value={search}
              onFocus={() => setIsFocus(true)}
              onBlur={() => setIsFocus(false)}
            />
            {isFocus && (
              <ButtonClose onClick={() => setSearch('')}>Close</ButtonClose>
            )}
          </InputContainer>
        </>
      );
    }
```